# Read half precision float (float16 IEEE 754r) binary data in matlab

Tags: matlab

you have been a great help last time, i hope you can give me some advise this time, too.

I read a binary file into matlab with bit16 (format = bitn) and i get a string of ones and zeros.

`bin = '1,00011,1111111111'` (16 bits: 1. sign, 2-6. exponent, 7-16. mantissa)

According to ftp://www.fox-toolkit.org/pub/fasthalffloatconversion.pdf it can be converted like

`out = (-1)^bin(1) * 2^(bin(2:6)-15) * 1.bin(7:16)` [are exponent and mantissa still binary?]

Can someone help me out and tell me how to deal with the 'eeeee' and '1.mmmmmmmmmm' as mentioned in the pdf, please.

Thanks a lot!

Michael

Comment: see this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/157099

Comment: @slayton: thanks for the link. I got that file before, but i got confused with the bitand(in,2139095040) where does the '2139095040' come from? Same issue some lines below.

Comment: @Michael: 2139095040 is in binary `0b1111111100000000000000000000000`, so if you do `bitand(bin, 2139095040) / 2^23` you get the value of `bin(31 ..24)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Guy](http://half.sourceforge.net/) made a wonderful C++ header file to deal with float16 - half precision float. Awesome!

Michael